# Running WLST file from cmd

Tags: wlst

I am trying to write a WLST script with .py extension. I have never used WLST before so I m having trouble in running the file.
Please help me with the steps to run a .py file from WLST for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/toc.htm) or the [tutorial](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/06-WLST--4474/cmdline.htm) could be a good start.
Starting WLST is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24491/using_wlst.htm#WLSTG254).

Answer (score 0):

This should work with this statement:

```
/opt/<your path here>/common/bin/wlst.sh /home/myscripts/myScript.py
```

The first part starts the WLST-Console.
The second part contains your python file.

In your script you can set the connection infos.

```
WLS_HOST = '<hostname>'
WLS_PORT = '<admin server port number-non SSL port>'
WLS_USER = '<weblogic user>'
WLS_PW = '<weblogic password>'
connect (WLS_USER,WLS_PW,WLS_HOST+ ':'+WLS_PORT)
```

Br.